# Why can't I multiple a css variable by a sass variable?

Tags: sass

@

```
mixin myMixin($mySassVarOne: 1) {
   --myCssVar: 2;

   $mySassVarTwo: var(--myCssVar);
   $result: $mySassVarOne * $mySassVarTwo; // (*)
   font-size: myFunction($result);
}

.myClass {
  @include myMixin(1);
}
```

**Why does (*) trigger error Undefined operation "1 * var(--myCssVar)" ?**

Comment: Because sass does not know or do calculations with pure CSS variables, so it's not looking up the variable if you use that notation. You could use `calc` and bypass this issue altogether.

Comment: myFunction needs to receive a number. that's why I put some sample values

Comment: You are confusing what SASS does with what CSS does. Because SASS is just a language to generate CSS, actual CSS is mixed in. But SASS _does not handle CSS variables_. You can use it to compute CSS variables, but it has _no knowledge_ of their values and cannot act on them. To do that, you need the inverse: `$sassVar1: 2; --myCssVar: var(#{$sassVar1});` - define SASS first, CSS second, because SASS _will convert to CSS in the end_.

Answer (score 1):

A CSS variable is unknown of value when processing it in sass - sass is just not made to 'compute' with them. It considers them like it considers keywords: just words, not values.

SASS will convert into CSS, so when writing it you have to keep your SASS first, your CSS second (because SASS can output CSS, but not the other way around!). The solution is to swap your variables:

```
@mixin myMixin($mySassVarOne: 1) {

   $mySassVarTwo: 2;

   --myCssVar: var(#{$mySassVarTwo});

   $result: $mySassVarOne * $mySassVarTwo; // (*)
   font-size: myFunction($result);
}

.myClass {
  @include myMixin(1);
}
```

Alternatively, you could go all-in on CSS and just do it all with regular variables and `calc` methods, but since I do not know what `myFunction` contains, I can't really tell you if it would work. I am also not 100% sure why you are using a CSS variable there, as it will be in your output even though you just want to use it to compute something *in SASS*. Since JS does not allow user named functions, I see no reason to use a CSS variable here.